trying to combine an if and filter function when the data choosen is from a drop down selection that contains ' to show a blank selection
i have a table with data in columns A-M and need to create a filter search based on 4 drop down selections.
so far i have this
=filter(data!A:M, (data!A:A=A3)*(data!L:L=A6), (data!D:D=A9)+ (data!E:E=A9)+ (data!F:F=A9)+ (data!C:C=A12)+ (data!G:G=A15)+ (data!H:H=A15)+ (data!I:I=A15)+ (data!J:J=A15))
now i would like it to return data if drop down a6 has the ', to show a blank line in dropdown, but drop down a9 has a pick from drop down
also may need to expand this so it will return results if any of the selections are blank but one is choosen
=filter(data!A:M, (data!A:A=A3)*(data!L:L=A6), (data!D:D=A9)+ (data!E:E=A9)+ (data!F:F=A9)+ (data!C:C=A12)+ (data!G:G=A15)+ (data!H:H=A15)+ (data!I:I=A15)+ (data!J:J=A15))
if i use an if function i cannot specify ' in formula as it thinks its part of the formula and wont let me carry on

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
